# StackLayout.FadeTo disables all buttons in the layout

Tags: ios, animation, mobile, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have these two functions in one of my pages (A Xamarin Forms for iOS project):

```
public void FadeOut(){
    pageLayout.FadeTo (0.5);
}

public void FadeIn(){
    pageLayout.FadeTo (1);
}
```

After running FadeOut() and than FadeIn(), none of the buttons/controls under this layout reacts, until I manipulate that page in some way that redraws the layout in some way.

If I do this instead:

```
public void FadeOut(){
        pageLayout.Opacity = 0.5;       
}

public void FadeIn(){
    pageLayout.Opacity = 1;
}
```

Everything works fine, but of course no animation.

Has anybody ever encountered such a weird problem? Any solutions?